# Python PyQt event not ignored

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have subclassed a qtextedit in my code with typical subclasing but somehow even if my signals works fine, event.ignore wont work.Goal is to catch enter key and click a button but not commit enter on the qtextedit.

My code is here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread , pyqtSignal

class Text_Edit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QEvent)
    keyPressed2 = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Text_Edit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 331, 71))
        self.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.raise_()
        self.setFocus()
        self.setPlaceholderText("Set 4 character ICAO Locator here , divided by spaces...")
        self.keyPressed.connect(self.on_key)


    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        super(Text_Edit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        self.keyPressed.emit(event) 

    def on_key(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            event.ignore()
            self.keyPressed2.emit()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1371, 924)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(True)


        self.T_aerodromes_input = Text_Edit(self.centralWidget)
        self.T_aerodromes_input.keyPressed2.connect(self.B_aerodrome_data.click)

        self.B_aerodrome_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_aerodrome_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 100, 271, 41))
        self.B_aerodrome_data.setObjectName("B_aerodrome_data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you want the QKeyEvent event to not trigger the task of cleaning the placeholder of the QTextEdit and instead want to activate the effect of pressing the button?

Comment: If you want the enter not to enter the QTextEdit remove `super(Text_Edit, self).keyPressEvent(event)`

Comment: Now all keys are disabled.., but enter works fine

Comment: see my answer..

Comment: You may want to look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter for another (more versatile) way of implementing the behaviour you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to filter the enter or return key then just verify that they are not those keys, if they are not those keys then call the father's method otherwise, do not do it.

```
def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    if event.key() not in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
         super(Text_Edit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
    else:
         self.keyPressed.emit(event)
```

Comment: I can't understand clearly why my approach didn't work , but this works fine.

Comment: is that you are ignoring an event different from the one used by the father, when you pass event through super(Text_Edit, self).keyPressEvent(event) a copy is generated that is the one that is passed internally, so the event that uses the father is a copy of which you ignore.